# Convert Char address back to __int64 or long

Tags: c++

I have defined a pointer address for window

```
#ifdef _WIN64 

    typedef uint64_t unit_pointer;

#   define PRINTF_PTR "%I64x"

#else

    typedef unsigned long unit_pointer;

#   define PRINTF_PTR "%lx"

#endif

TEST *obj = &test_obj;

char obj_pointer_add[50]; 

sprintf(obj_pointer_add, PRINTF_PTR, (unit_pointer)obj);
```

Now i want to recreate the obj pointer in other place, given that i know obj_pointer_add.
How could i convert back obj_pointer_add to unit_pointer?

```
unit_pointer point_address= (unit_pointer)obj_pointer_add; (ERROR CONVERTING)

TEST *new_obj = reinterpret_cast<TEST *>(point_address); (fail because of pointer_address wrong)
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you know the pointers are unsigned 64 bit numbers?

Comment: I want to make sure I understand what you really want.  You sprintf'd the address into a human readable form, and then you want to go from that human readable form back into a valid address?

Comment: If you want to use `printf` to print a pointer, you should use the `"%p"` format.

Comment: I have tried in this way and it works. 
TEST *obj = &test_obj; 
unit_pointer obj_pointer = obj; 
TEST *new_obj = (TEST *)(obj_pointer); (Working)

Comment: @user2168906 *"I have tried in this way and it works"* : So the question is.... ?

Comment: Now i wish to convert the unit_pointer  to char , store it, then retrieve back from char to unit_pointer.. Stuck at the conversion of char to unit_pointer

Comment: You do know that a pointer in one program will not be usable in another program? Or even in the same program if running it twice.

Comment: Char occupies one byte in memory, unit_pointer occupies four of them, how would you like the conversion to work?

Answer (score 3):

I really have no idea why you need this. But, I suggest you this easier way (IMO) to get rid of those `"#if / #endif"` :

```
TEST *obj = new TEST();

std::stringstream stream;                //
stream << std::hex << obj;               //Convert address to a hex-string
std::string hex_str_addr(stream.str());  //

// ...

std::uintptr_t addr;
std::stringstream(hex_str_addr) >> std::hex >> addr; //Convert back to a address

TEST *new_obj = reinterpret_cast<TEST*>(addr);
```

Use `uintptr_t` which is aware of your system pointer size.

Answer (score 0):

You could `sscanf` it, using the same format, into a variable.

**Note:** You can **only** do this in the *exact* same process. So if you store the pointer and restart your program, you can not use the stored pointer again. And if you use it to pass around pointer in the same process, why would you want it as a string, instead of using the actual pointer?